# If $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ and uniformly continuous on every $(a,b)$ so it also uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

*If there exists the same question with answer anywhere, plz delete this one, i didn't find one.

If $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ and uniformly continuous on every $(a,b)$ so it is also uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$

I think the statement is correct.

---

### My attempt:

I think it is not true, since it can be that in every interval $(a,b)$ i can have a different gradient, which is constant for every interval, therefore, every interval has a finite $\delta > 0$ but with infinity number of intervals, each one may have a bigger gradient, in this case, i wont find $\delta > 0$ which is not dependent on $x$.

Therefore, the statment is not correct for every $f$.

Do i correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Here's a hint for how to think about it: any continuous function is uniformly continuous on the compact set $[a,b]$ and hence on $(a,b)$. So from the hint we see that the question is asking if every continuous function is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Nice thinking, and we know its generally not correct. I didnt think that way, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement is false.

Consider $f(x) = x^2$. Observe $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and 
\begin{align}
|x^2-y^2|\leq |x+y||x-y|\leq 2\max(|a|, |b|)|x-y|
\end{align}
for all $x, y \in (a, b)$, i.e. $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a, b)$. But is clear that $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you for the details as for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The logic about what can go wrong is correct but this doesn't really prove the statement is wrong. You need a specific counterexample. Well, it is easy, take $f(x)=x^2$. Actually, any function which is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ but not uniformly continuous there is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for the help